# Error: data truncated for column 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, function

So far all the results I'm finding for this error are in reference to some additional code (phpmyadmin or python) so I'm a little confused. Had issues with my form yesterday but that appears to be resolved. So, now I appear to be having an issue with the drop down lists I've created. They function fine in regards to actually displaying a list from a MySQL query but they don't appear to be selecting the correct value.

Here's the Form:

```
<form action="/php/newcarcodetest.php" method="post">
   <table style="width:575px">
      <tr>
         <th>Make</th>
         <td><select name="make" style="width:344px"><?php make() ?></select></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Model</th>
         <td><select name="model" style="width:344px"><?php model() ?></select></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here's the function:

```
function make() {
    $qmake=mysql_query("SELECT VMakeID, VMake FROM vmake");
    while($record=mysql_fetch_array($qmake)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$record['VMakeID'].'">'.$record['VMake'].'</option>';
    }
}

function model() {
    $qmodel=mysql_query("SELECT VModelID, VModel FROM vmodel");
    while($record=mysql_fetch_array($qmodel)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$record['VModelID'].'">'.$record['VModel'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

And then here's the php for the form:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server","mycaradmin","SuperSecretPassword","mycars");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$make=$_POST["make"];
$model=$_POST["model"];
$sql="INSERT INTO mycars.vehicles (VMakeID,VModelID)
      VALUES ('$make','$model;')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Like I said, the functionality of the dropdown is working fine. And I know I need to work on reducing the possibility of SQL injections but I'm just trying to get it working at this point. When I click the submit button it takes me to a blank page with the error:

Error: Data truncated for column 'VModelID' at row 1

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the value of `$make`, what is the DB definition of the column  `VModelID`, also ever heard of SQL injection?

Comment: `'$model;'` seems like a typo.

Comment: @Muer, I think you got it, this ';' might be the overflowing char ;)

Comment: That did it - THANK YOU!! That was driving me nuts. Spent way too much time staring at that yesterday for it to be something so simple. Thanks!!